# Algebra of Noether's charges and algebra of symmetry transformations

Tags: symmetry, hamiltonian-formalism, conventions, classical-field-theory, poisson-brackets

I'm trying to understand the connection of algebra of transformations under a commutator and algebra of Noether's charges under Poisson bracket.

I have a problem that results I infer from theoretical consideration do not match with results I get for simple example - free scalar theory in two dimensions. I am making a mistake somewhere but I am not sure where.

**Theoretical approach:**

Let us assume we have symmetry transformation $f^\mu$ such that
$$\delta_f \phi(x) = \phi'(x) - \phi(x) = f^\mu(x)\partial_\mu\phi(x).$$

From this I would expect that commutator of the symmetry transformations is
$$[\delta_f, \delta_g]\phi = (f^\mu\partial_\mu g^\nu - g^\mu\partial_\mu f^\nu)\partial_\nu\phi \equiv h^\nu\partial_\nu\phi = \delta_h\phi.$$

There are a lot questions on this page proving and discussing that conserved Noether's charge $Q_f$ generates symmetry, i.e.
$$\delta_f\phi(x) = \{\phi(x), Q_f\},$$
where the Poisson bracket is
$$\{A(\textbf{x},t), B(\textbf{y},t)\} =\int d{\textbf{x'}} \frac{\delta A(\textbf{x},t)}{\delta\phi(\textbf{x'},t)}\frac{\delta B(\textbf{y},t)}{\delta\pi(\textbf{x'},t)} - \frac{\delta A(\textbf{x},t)}{\delta\pi(\textbf{x'},t)}\frac{\delta B(\textbf{y},t)}{\delta\phi(\textbf{x'},t)}$$

From here I would expect

$$\delta_h\phi= [\delta_f,\delta_g]\phi = \delta_f\delta_g\phi - \delta_g\delta_f\phi = \{\{\phi, Q_g\},Q_f\} - \{\{\phi,Q_f\},Q_g\} $$
$$\stackrel{\text{Jacobi id.}}{=} -\{\{Q_g, Q_f\}, \phi\} = -\{\phi,\{Q_f,Q_g\}\} \equiv \{\phi,Q_h\}$$

From which I conclude
$$Q_h = -\{Q_f, Q_g\}$$

**Example of free scalar field:**

I want to illustrate previous considerations on a simple theory

$$ I = \int d^2x \frac12 \partial_\mu\phi\partial^\mu\phi$$

This action is invariant under $f^\mu$ being conformal Killing vector in flat space, i.e. $f^\mu$ satisfy
$$\partial_\mu f_\nu + \partial_\nu f_\mu = \eta_{\mu\nu}\partial_\rho f^\rho.$$

Using Noether's theorem I derived the conserved charge associated with the symmetry
$$Q_f = \int dx \Big[\frac12((\partial_x\phi)^2+\pi^2)f^t+f^x\pi\partial_x\phi\Big]$$

From this I have
$$\frac{\delta Q_f}{\delta\pi(x,t)} = f^t\pi + f^x\partial_x\phi, \qquad     \frac{\delta Q_f}{\delta \phi(x,t)} =-\partial_x( f^t\partial_x\phi+\pi f^x)$$

This charge really satisfies equation
$$\delta_f = \{\phi, Q_f\}$$

But the problematic result I get is
$$\{Q_f, Q_g\} = Q_h.$$
No minus is here.

I believe the ambiguity is in evaluating
$$\delta_f\delta_g\phi,$$
because Poisson bracket ignores the $g^\mu$ and $f^\mu$. While in the theoretical approach I expected
$$\delta_f(g^\mu\partial_\mu\phi)= f^\nu\partial_\nu(f^\mu\partial_\mu\phi)$$
there I didn't ignore $g^\mu$.

But I am missing the physical reasoning here and I do see know which result is correct.

Comment: So you are asking about a minus sign?

Comment: Yes, that's the difference in the results I got.